# iOS - change audio assets BeatsPerMinute metadata tag

Tags: ios, avfoundation, itunes, avaudiosession, core-media

**Problem**: I want to modify the iTunes song beats per minute.

**Solution that I am trying:** modifying the beats per minute of an audio asset `AVAsset`. I have used this code.

```
AVMutableMetadataItem *metaBeats = [AVMutableMetadataItem metadataItem];
metaBeats.identifier = AVMetadataIdentifierID3MetadataBeatsPerMinute;
metaBeats.key = AVMetadataIdentifierID3MetadataBeatsPerMinute;
metaBeats.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceID3;
metaBeats.value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:40];
```

I have also used the other key`AVMetadataIdentifieriTunesMetadataBeatsPerMin` but no option is working at all.

`AVAssetExportSession` export function is working fine.

I have seen other Q/As on stackoverflow which updates the metadata Common key tags that are working fine but this is not working at all.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Here is the link to project code
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6cdos0k21b2fi3y/MusicEffectBeats.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *inputURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample" 
withExtension:@"m4a"];
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:inputURL];
```

In the above code i cannot see your sample.m4a file

[image]

Comment: sample.m4a file is there ... please check the project directory.
Open the dropbox link, you will get it there ...